# Equivalent data type for SQL_Variant in sql server not found in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql

I cannot find any equivalent datatype for SQL_Variant in potgresql. Sql_variant is available in sql server. I am new to postgres and presently migrating from sql server to postgres.

Comment: For those of us that don't use SQL Server: what is this `SQL_Variant` type? What exactly does it do?

Answer (score 4):

There is no such data type in PostgreSQL.

You can either use several attributes, one for each possible type (and maybe a `CHECK` constraint that assures that exactly one of them is `NOT NULL`) or store binary data (type `bytea`) and convert them to whatever data type you need in the application.

Answer (score 1):

Here is about `sql_variant` link [sql_variant (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql)

I would say the closest you could get is to declare a text column and 
store the string representations of the values.